# ERROR [stderr] (EJB default - 8) java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.sqlite.JDBC

Tags: java, sqlite, jakarta-ee, ejb, database-connection

I'm trying to make a connection with sqlite database in j2ee project, but i keep getting this error "ERROR [stderr] (EJB default -8)java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.sqlite.JDBC". Knowing that I test the method in java program and that's work fine.
I have one connection class in ejb project(session bean)there is the code here.

```
public Connection getConnection(){
    Connection connection= null;


    try {
        Class.forName("org.sqlite.JDBC");
        String dataFolder = System.getProperty("user.home") + "\\AppData\\Local";
        String b = System.getProperty("user.home") ;



        String file = b + "\\Desktop\\file";
        connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite:"+ file );
       System.out.println("Connection completed.");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return connection;
 }
```

then I test it with junit test in java project but everytime i get the same error :java.Lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.sqlite.JDBC 
PS: I have incuded sqlite.jar like this (right click on the project->configure build path-> library-> add external jar) but always facing the same error

Comment: The `java.Lang.ClassNotFoundException` occurs when really?! Both when your application is running and when you're running your JUnit tests?

Comment: when I run my junit test @aribeiro

Comment: Are you using Maven to build and package your application?

Comment: I'm using jboss 7.1 as a server and eclipse as an IDE  @aribeiro

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have fixed the problem:

1. Added *SQLite* jar file in this path:

   D:\jboss-as-7.1.1.Final\modules\javax\activation\api\main
2. In *JBoss Server Runtime* > *Deployments* > *Manage Deployments* added *SQLite* jar file an then enable it.

Comment: Where is Jboss server runtime > Deployments > Manage Deployments in eclipse?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you have the following project structure:

```
src/main/java
     |
      - MyConnection.java
src/test/java
     |
      - MyConnectionTest.java
```

With the following elements:

Base class `MyConnection`

```
public class MyConnection {

    public Connection getConnection() {
        Connection connection = null;

        try {
            Class.forName("org.sqlite.JDBC");
            connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite:");
            System.out.println("Connection completed.");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return connection;
    }
}
```

Test class `MyConnectionTest`

```
import static org.junit.Assert.assertFalse;
import static org.junit.Assert.assertTrue;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.SQLException;

import org.junit.Test;

public class MyConnectionTest {

    @Test
    public void isValid() throws SQLException {
        MyConnection myConn = new MyConnection();
        Connection conn = myConn.getConnection();
        assertTrue(conn.isValid(0));
        conn.close();
        assertFalse(conn.isValid(0));
    }
}
```

In your Eclipse project you just need to do the following:

1. Right click on your project;
2. Navigate to *Build Path* and select the option *Configure Build Path...*;
3. On your right side menu, press *Add Library*, select *JUnit* (JUnit4) and click *Finish*;
4. Finally, on the *Configure Build Path...* menu, select the option *Add External JARs...*, browse to the location where your [SQLite JDBC jar](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.xerial/sqlite-jdbc/3.8.11.2) file is, select it and click on *Apply*.
5. Go to your `MyConnectionTest` test class and run it as a JUnit test.

Comment: I get the same error : ERROR [stderr] (EJB default - 10) java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.sqlite.JDBC from [Module "deployment.mrhelp-server-ejb.jar:main" from Service Module Loader]. My project structure is like that:
mrhelp-server-ejb -> ejbmoule->connection package->connection.java,connectionRemote
mrhelp-client->conection delegate package->connection delagate.java
   ->connectionTest package->test connection.java

Comment: the connection delagate is here:  
private static String jndi="ejb:/mrhelp-server-ejb/ManageService!tn.esprit.tex.gestion.service.connectionRemote";
 static connectionRemote getProxy(){
  
  return (connectionRemote) ServiceLocator.getInstance().getProxy(jndi);
 }
 public static Connection getConnection() {
  return getProxy().getConnection();
  
 }

Comment: @user2096996, the error you've just posted refers to the *mrhelp-server-ejb.jar* file. How are you executing your tests?

Comment: there is the code of test connection
@Test
public void dotest() throws SQLException {


ConnectionDelegate.getConnection();



connection myConn = new connection();
Connection conn = myConn.getConnection();
assertTrue(conn.isValid(0));
conn.close();
assertFalse(conn.isValid(0));
}

Comment: @user2096996, can you please update your question with the information mentioned in the last comments? And, if possible, please format it.